# (socket.io) How to make a server only accept one connection from a device?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want make my server only accept one connection from a device(that means people can not open several browsers to connect my server), and I use client ip to identify connections. The question is if two devices are from the same ethernet their ip address will be the same(so they can not connect to my server the same time).

I tried to use `socket.request.connection.remotePort` to get the client port, but it shows different every connection even in the same browser.

Comment: try remoteAddress

Comment: remoteAddress is same as the client ip

Comment: You want the IP address, not the port number so I have no idea why you're trying to use `.remotePort`.  Further, you will block lots of legitimate cases if you block more than one user from the same IP.  For example, you will block more than one person coming from the same house and, in some cases, coming from the same business or school.  Internet IP address is not 1-to-1 with a computer because of NAT and proxies where many computers on a private network may share the same public IP address (using different ports) when accessing the internet.

Comment: You should accomplish what you're trying to do by using a user login and enforcing one login per user and enforcing only one account per actual user.

Comment: Thx. 
> you will block lots of legitimate cases if you block more than one user from the same IP. 
That's exactly what I am worried about. `user login` is a good way, the problem is I have no login-system in my website yet. Therefore I want get something like `mac address` to identify device(it seems impossible to get mac address from client).